# How to compare two given dates with date coming from datetime field in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have got user entered Datetime fields like `CreatedON` and `CreatedEND` and these are having datetime formats like (29-02-2013) and (12-04-2013) (these are sample values only)

I have got one column in sql server like `CreatedDatetime`  and values like this 2013-09-03 and 2013-02-03 (these are sample values only)
Now I need to check whether the CreatedDatetime field is in between `CreatedON` and `CreatedEND` two given dates...

How can i compare the date coming from database with these two values..
this comparison  need to be done  in sql server only

Would any one suggest any ideas and solutions for this ..
Many thanks In advance..

**EDIT :**

```
   DECLARE  @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[tp_SelectTransactionHistorySearch]
        @OffSetRowNo = 1,
        @FetchRowNo = 1,
        @StatusSelection = N's',
        @isReviewed = NULL,
        @ProjectCaseNumber = NULL,
        @CostPageNumber = NULL,
        @TransactionTypeChange = NULL,
        @DescriptionChange = NULL,
        @TrasactionCreateOnBeginDate = N'19-03-2013',
        @TransactionCreatedOnEndDate = N'20-03-2013',
        @TransactionUpdatedOnBeginDate = N'10-04-2013',
        @TransactionUpdateOnEndDate = N'11-04-2013',
        @ItemID = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

**ERROR :** Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure tp_SelectTransactionHistorySearch, Line 0
    Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

Comment: hmm i have stored those ones as dates only ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using CAST like this:-

```
(CreatedDatetime >= CAST(CreatedON AS DATE)) AND (CreatedDatetime < CAST(CreatedEND AS DATE))
```

Comment: pls see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328297/not-able-to-pass-input-parameters-to-stored-procedure/18328437?noredirect=1#18328437  I am getting error at the conversions...

Comment: my problem is like this ... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/01e42813-b4af-4136-9b45-b76fa028801f/conversion-failed-when-passing-datetime-input-to-sp-parameter conversion is failing when i want to convert to the date from string

Comment: @pratapk:- Is this your original question???http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328297/not-able-to-pass-input-parameters-to-stored-procedure/18328437?noredirect=1#18328437...I would recommend you to stick to this question only or may be post one more question detailing out your problem. The above question was different when you asked but now you have changed that. So most probably it will noy attract other people attention. :)

Answer (score 0):

If user entering a date from another system/program then use parameters:

```
DECLARE @CreatedON AS DATETIME = '';
DECLARE @CreatedEND AS DATETIME = '';

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CreatedDatetime BETWEEN @CreatedON AND @CreatedEnd 
    THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
```

But if values are already stored in database then just compare fields as

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CreatedDatetime BETWEEN CreatedON AND CreatedEnd 
    THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
FROM TimeTable
```

Or if they stored as string(dd-mm-yyyy) then:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CreatedDatetime BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CreatedON, 105) AND
              CONVERT(DATETIME, CreatedEnd, 105) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
```