# Not able to pass input parameters to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have store procedure like this getting values from database based upon the search criteria that I am passing those ones are as input parameters to that procedure but I am getting error at `@StatusSelection`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tp_SelectTransactionHistorySearch]
(
   @OffSetRowNo INT,     
   @FetchRowNo INT,
   @StatusSelection NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @isReviewed Bit,
   @ProjectCaseNumber VARCHAR(MAX),
   @CostPageNumber VARCHAR(MAX),
   @TransactionTypeChange VARCHAR(MAX),
   @DescriptionChange VARCHAR(MAX),
   @TrasactionCreateOnBeginDate DATETIME,
   @TransactionCreatedOnEndDate DATETIME,
   @TransactionUpdatedOnBeginDate DATETIME,
   @TransactionUpdateOnEndDate DATETIME,
   @ItemID VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
 Select 
            TH.TransactionID,
            TH.IsReviewed,
            TH.ItemID,
            TH.CostPageNumber,
            TH.Comments,
            TH.CreatedBy,
            TH.CreatedDateTime,
            TH.UpdatedBy,
            TH.UpdatedDateTime,
            TH.TransactionDescription,
            TH.TransactionTypeID,
            IAccrualByItem.PROJCASE,
            IAccrualByItem.USTSTAT as TransactionStatusID,
            TStatType.Name AS TransactionStatusTypeName,
            TStatType.Description AS TransactionStatusTypeDescription,   
            TType.Name AS TransactionTypeName,
            TType.Description AS TransactionTypeDescription,
            COUNT(*) OVER () as TotalCount
        FROM TransactionHistory AS TH
        INNER JOIN TRVMVSDDVW001.INTERFACE_Files.dbo.DBATUSTA AS IAccrualByItem
            ON TH.TransactionID = CAST(IAccrualByItem.USTTRNNBR AS int)
        LEFT JOIN dbo.TransctionStatusType AS TStatType
            ON TStatType.TransactionStatusTypeID = IAccrualByItem.USTSTAT
        LEFT JOIN dbo.TransactionType AS TType
            ON TType.TransactionTypeID = CAST(TH.TransactionTypeID AS int)
        WHERE TStatType.Name = @StatusSelection AND TH.IsReviewed= @isReviewed
        AND IAccrualByItem.PROJCASE=@ProjectCaseNumber AND TH.CostPageNumber=@CostPageNumber
        AND TH.TransactionDescription=@TransactionTypeChange AND TType.Description=@DescriptionChange
        AND  (TH.CreatedDateTime >= CAST(@TrasactionCreateOnBeginDate AS DATE)) AND (TH.CreatedDateTime < CAST(@TransactionCreatedOnEndDate AS DATE))
         AND  (TH.UpdatedDateTime >= CAST( @TransactionUpdatedOnBeginDate AS DATE)) AND (TH.UpdatedDateTime < CAST(@TransactionUpdateOnEndDate AS DATE))
         @TH.StatusID= 1
GROUP BY TH.TransactionID,TH.IsReviewed,TH.ItemID,TH.CostPageNumber,TH.Comments,TH.CreatedBy,TH.CreatedDateTime,
TH.UpdatedBy,TH.UpdatedDateTime, TH.TransactionDescription, TH.TransactionTypeID,IAccrualByItem.PROJCASE,TransactionStatusID,
TStatType.Name,TStatType.Description,TType.Name,TType.Description
ORDER BY TH.TransactionID,TH.ItemID,TH.CostPageNumber
OFFSET ( @OffSetRowNo-1 ) * @FetchRowNo ROWS
FETCH NEXT @FetchRowNo ROWS ONLY
```

But i am getting error like this

```
 `Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 27
 Must declare the scalar variable "@StatusSelection"`.
```

I am using sql server 2012 version

would any one pls help on this solution and any ideas on this ..
Many thanks .....

**UPDATE:**

```
    DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[tp_SelectTransactionHistorySearch]
        @OffSetRowNo = 1,
        @FetchRowNo = 1,
        @StatusSelection = N's',
        @isReviewed = NULL,
        @ProjectCaseNumber = NULL,
        @CostPageNumber = NULL,
        @TransactionTypeChange = NULL,
        @DescriptionChange = NULL,
        @TrasactionCreateOnBeginDate = '10-03-2013',
        @TransactionCreatedOnEndDate = '20-03-2013',
        @TransactionUpdatedOnBeginDate = '20-05-2013',
        @TransactionUpdateOnEndDate = '04-06-2013',
        @ItemID = NULL

   SELECT   'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Getting error like this `Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure tp_SelectTransactionHistorySearch, Line 0
Error converting data type varchar to datetime`.

Comment: Try @StatusSelection NVARCHAR(MAX)=null

Comment: TStatType.Name = @StatusSelection...in this line could you change this to TStatType.Name = isnull(@StatusSelection,'') or may be TStatType.Name =isnull(@StatusSelection, null)??

Comment: @pratapk:- Do let me know what you get after this change??

Comment: @RahulTripathi     i have changed that one i have got problem with date conversion ...i have got database values like 09-09-2013 , 08-07-2013 ... i have got incoming values are like above mentioned in update but I am getting conversion error ....

Comment: I am really sorry but I am not able to get your point very clearly...but what I am getting is you are not able to CAST the varchar value to a DATETIME field. For that I have already answered you in the question:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327812/how-to-compare-two-give-dates-with-datetime-field-in-sql-server/18327898?noredirect=1#comment26901773_18327898

Comment: Can you use the SQL Profiler to know get actually where the problem is?? Is it in @StatusSelection??

Comment: Hmm I have already solved the problem with  @StatusSelection , then its working fine ...I have used your cast mentioned in last question , but getting error pls look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327812/how-to-compare-two-given-dates-with-date-coming-from-datetime-field-in-sql-serve

Comment: Use `CONVERT`, there you can set a format of string for `DATETIME` - [CAST and CONVERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tp_SelectTransactionHistorySearch] 
(
    @OffSetRowNo INT,
    @FetchRowNo INT,
    @StatusSelection NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @isReviewed BIT,
    @ProjectCaseNumber VARCHAR(MAX),
    @CostPageNumber VARCHAR(MAX),
    @TransactionTypeChange VARCHAR(MAX),
    @DescriptionChange VARCHAR(MAX),
    @TrasactionCreateOnBeginDate DATE,
    @TransactionCreatedOnEndDate DATE,
    @TransactionUpdatedOnBeginDate DATE,
    @TransactionUpdateOnEndDate DATE,
    @ItemID VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
    SELECT TH.TransactionID
        ,  TH.IsReviewed
        ,  TH.ItemID
        ,  TH.CostPageNumber
        ,  TH.Comments
        ,  TH.CreatedBy
        ,  TH.CreatedDateTime
        ,  TH.UpdatedBy
        ,  TH.UpdatedDateTime
        ,  TH.TransactionDescription
        ,  TH.TransactionTypeID
        ,  IAccrualByItem.PROJCASE
        ,  IAccrualByItem.USTSTAT AS TransactionStatusID
        ,  TStatType.Name AS TransactionStatusTypeName
        ,  TStatType.[description] AS TransactionStatusTypeDescription
        ,  TType.Name AS TransactionTypeName
        ,  TType.[description] AS TransactionTypeDescription
        ,  COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount
    FROM TransactionHistory AS TH
    JOIN TRVMVSDDVW001.INTERFACE_Files.dbo.DBATUSTA AS IAccrualByItem ON TH.TransactionID = CAST(IAccrualByItem.USTTRNNBR AS INT)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.TransctionStatusType AS TStatType ON TStatType.TransactionStatusTypeID= IAccrualByItem.USTSTAT
    LEFT JOIN dbo.TransactionType AS TType ON TType.TransactionTypeID = CAST(TH.TransactionTypeID AS INT)
    WHERE TStatType.Name = @StatusSelection
        AND TH.IsReviewed = @isReviewed
        AND IAccrualByItem.PROJCASE = @ProjectCaseNumber
        AND TH.CostPageNumber = @CostPageNumber
        AND TH.TransactionDescription = @TransactionTypeChange
        AND TType.[description] = @DescriptionChange
        AND TH.CreatedDateTime BETWEEN @TrasactionCreateOnBeginDate AND @TransactionCreatedOnEndDate
        AND TH.UpdatedDateTime BETWEEN @TransactionUpdatedOnBeginDate AND @TransactionUpdateOnEndDate
        AND TH.StatusID = 1
    GROUP BY
          TH.TransactionID
        , TH.IsReviewed
        , TH.ItemID
        , TH.CostPageNumber
        , TH.Comments
        , TH.CreatedBy
        , TH.CreatedDateTime
        , TH.UpdatedBy
        , TH.UpdatedDateTime
        , TH.TransactionDescription
        , TH.TransactionTypeID
        , IAccrualByItem.PROJCASE
        , TransactionStatusID
        , TStatType.Name
        , TStatType.[description]
        , TType.Name
        , TType.[description]
    ORDER BY 
          TH.TransactionID
        , TH.ItemID
        , TH.CostPageNumber
    OFFSET (@OffSetRowNo - 1) * @FetchRowNo ROWS FETCH NEXT @FetchRowNo ROWS ONLY
```

**Update #1:**

Set this option, before executing your query -

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
```

or, more preferable, use `ISO` format `yyyymmdd` -

```
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[tp_SelectTransactionHistorySearch]
    ...
    @TrasactionCreateOnBeginDate = '20130310',
    @TransactionCreatedOnEndDate = '20132003',
    @TransactionUpdatedOnBeginDate = '20130520',
    @TransactionUpdateOnEndDate = '20130604',
    @ItemID = NULL
```

**Update #2:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    string VARCHAR(10)
)

SET DATEFORMAT dmy 

INSERT INTO @temp (string)
VALUES 
    ('10-03-2013'),
    ('20-03-2013'),
    ('20-05-2013'),
    ('04-06-2013')

SELECT CAST(string AS DATE) 
FROM @temp
```

Comment: I think you need to mention what you did to make this work. Specifically how this removed the error message about `@StatusSelection`.

Comment: That does not fix the error OP had. Granted, the code posted is not what gave that error but don't you think it would be helpful if you mentioned that the error posted in the Q is not related to the code?. And you do not need an order by in `count(*) over()` so that one was just fine as is.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson thanks for the comment. I rollback changes in `COUNT(*) OVER ()`. I think the main syntax error in `@TH.StatusID= 1`. Just need to change it to `AND TH.StatusID = 1`

Comment: sorry , i removed `@` symbol from this `@TH.StatusID= 1` now i am getting another error `Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure tp_SelectTransactionHistorySearch, Line 0
Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime`. how can i resolve this one ....pls help and thanks for this solution

Comment: @Devart  I have mentioned   `@TrasactionCreateOnBeginDate DATETIME,
    @TransactionCreatedOnEndDate DATETIME,
    @TransactionUpdatedOnBeginDate DATETIME,
    @TransactionUpdateOnEndDate DATETIME` these ones as date time and I hav got these ones also  `TH.CreatedDateTime` and `TH.UpdatedDateTime` datetime columns but why I am getting that error

Comment: @pratapk: show us how the code you use to call this procedure. The error you have is caused byt missing parameters. So are you using SQLParameter correctly? Or using String concatenation?

Comment: And also provide with what parameters you exec your sp.

Comment: @Devart pls see my  update  I am passing the date value like that when i execute that it was giving error

Comment: @Devart I have got database values like this (09-09-2013 , 08-07-2013) so how can i convert those ones into these format `yyyymmdd` in store procedure pls suggest any ideas

Comment: how can i cast these values 09-09-2013 , 08-07-2013 into 20130909, 20130708 so that i compare in string format .....

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I think that you should store data-types in your tables into good order. If data is the `DATE` data-type, you should not store it as strings.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
@TH.StatusID= 1
```

means the CREATE fails

So you can't get the error you have shown with the code you gave us

With this, CREATE works

```
 AND TH.StatusID= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you pass the values in code behind side ?

```
     SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SpName",conectionStringObj);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     **com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusSelection", "Any Value");**
       .
       .
       .
       .
```

Please check this .

Comment: Sorry If u misunderstood I am executing this store procedure inside sql server it self ..